# How to generate a sequence of numbers when encountered a value in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[sample and expected data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f92mo.jpg)

The block one is current data and block 2 is the expected data that is, when i encounter 1 i need the next row to be incremented by one and for next country b same should happen

Comment: in simple terms when the value == 1 then next column value should increment by 1. wasn't able to solve it yet

Comment: OK, please test my solution with your real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace all another values after first `1` to `1`, so is possible use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':['a']*3 + ['b']*3+ ['c']*3, 'v':[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]})

s = df.groupby('c')['v'].cumsum()
df['new'] = s.where(s.eq(0), 1).groupby(df['c']).cumsum()
print (df)
   c  v  new
0  a  1    1
1  a  0    2
2  a  0    3
3  b  0    0
4  b  1    1
5  b  0    2
6  c  0    0
7  c  0    0
8  c  1    1
```

Another solution is replace all not `1` values to missing values and forward filling `1` per groups, then first missing values are replaced to `0`, so cumulative sum also working perfectly:

```
s = df['v'].where(df['v'].eq(1)).groupby(df['c']).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
df['new'] = s.groupby(df['c']).cumsum()
```